# How to get Two articles in One list using salesforce query

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, sosl, describesobject, describefieldresult

Hi every one I have a two articles: `Offer__kav` and `Offer_order__kav`.

How to Query This Two Objects Related All Fields.

For Ex: I tried :

```
List<List<SObject>> search_results = [FIND 'SFDC' RETURNING Offer__kav(Title), Offer_order__kav(Title,)];
```

Comment: Hi Khushboo Dua, THank you, i need to add Multiple Articles dynamically How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below query, Its working fine.

```
List<List<Sobject>> search_results = [FIND 'How is BB' RETURNING Test1__kav (Id,Article1__c),Test2__kav(Id, KnowledgeArticleId)];
```

Comment: Hi @magi 001, would you mind providing minimal explanation to your code so others may better understand your answer? (Its working fine doesnt really help others learnf from your post) please take a moment to review [answer], very much appreciated!